# command sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Does the following code means that it is not install and any suggestion for It

```
r-master/libcrafter$ sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpcap0.8-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 133 not upgraded.
Need to get 209 kB of archives.
After this operation, 712 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libpcap0.8-dev
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main libpcap0.8-dev amd64 1.6.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpcap/libpcap0.8-dev_1.6.2-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
altaf@altaf-Lenovo-G50-70:~/Desktop/CNProjactProgram/libcrafter-master/libcrafter-master/libcrafter$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it definitely means that. The package is not installed, and it is because the package repository in use isn't working and won't work for your current version of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 14.10 was end-of-lifed as of July 23, 2015. So, it isn't up on the Ubuntu mirrors.

You could:

### Use the Old Releases Mirror

In `/etc/apt.conf`, change all references to `http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`:

```
sudo sed -i 's/in.archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt.conf
```

I considered noting here that you could also install from a 14.10 CD or ISO, but that doesn't actually "fix" your problem, it's just a work-around.

Alternately, and what I would do personally:

### Use a New (or LTS) Version of Ubuntu

Using an Long Term Support version (14.04.3 is the latest right now) is never a bad idea, because it helps avoid issues like the one you're having right now. 14.04, for example, is supported through **April 2019**.

Or, you could simply upgrade from 14.10 to a more recent regular release of Ubuntu; the latest is 15.10.

You can see the lifetimes of the different version here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Oops, nope. Fixing.

Comment: @AltafShaikh yes, we are aware of that as your output shows `utopic`.

Comment: Can you suggest to which version i should upgrade my Ubuntu??

Comment: @AltafShaikh If you want to go that route, either 14.04.3 or 15.10 would be the reasonable options. Personally, I always use the LTS releases because they are much more stable, so I'm typing from a 14.04.3 machine. A person could prefer 15.10 if they are wanting more recently released software packages. To me, the instability and thrashing between Ubuntu mainline releases is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with it

```
rm /usr/share/doc/libpcap0.8-dev/*
rm /usr/share/man/man7/pcap-filter.7.gz

download .deb
dpkg -i libpcap0.8_1.10.1-4_amd64.deb

apt --fix-broken install
```

that fixed my issue, if people look for a solution